# Help to check power supply board on hifi system (Sony MHC/HCD - GZR5D)

Tags: power-supply

Issue - Hifi System not powering on

Model - Sony MHC/HCD - GZR5D

Service Manual - [Attached](https://easyupload.io/wa4oba) (page 61)

Help Needed - I need to understand which points on the board I can use to check with multimeter to check if main transformer is working.
[image]

Comment: please provide a direct http link to the pdf data sheet/manual

Comment: https://easyupload.io/wa4oba

Answer (score 1):

From the circuit diagram (Page 62) of the board, it appears that there are two transformers. T002 is connected directly to the mains input and supplies DC and an AC Detect signal to the Main board via CN002 also marked J. I am guessing that, when the power switch is operated a signal is returned via "Relay" (pin 1 J) to operate RY002 at the top of the diagram and hence apply the mains to the main transformer T001.
When you press the power switch can you hear this relay operate? If so there are several pairs of terminals on J and it's companion connector I (AKA CN001) which you can measure for the presence of an AC voltage. For example pins 2 and 3 on I. I haven't read all 100+ pages of the manual, so I don't know what to expect, so use a multimeter and start on a fairly high AC voltage range.
The main transformer has a built in, non-replaceable fuse. If the relay operates but no AC voltage appears on any of the output terminals then this has possibly blown and, sadly, the board is kaput.
And finally a word of caution. All the time the equipment is plugged in there are live mains voltage tracks on this board. Even more of it goes live if the relay is operated, so unless you know what you are doing, leave it to someone who does. Most of the left hand side of the board (the white hatched area) as shown in your photograph could potentially be at mains potential, which is not to say the right hand side is 100% safe either.

Comment: If I connect the plug to AC socket, I don't hear any 'tick' sound at all(I used to hear that when this system was working)
Also no relay sounds when power button on the system is pressed.

Comment: @Simon Please measure if you have any AC voltage on transformer secondary.

Comment: @winny I would like to first check if I have power on the AC primary?

But I am struggling to understand which pins I should use for that? If you can help me with that from the circuit diagram perspective.

Comment: @Simon Oh, that’s first order of business.

Comment: @winny I see 6 terminals for T001 transformer primary coil. I am trying to understand which terminal to be used for checking if input AC voltage reach the transformer T001

Comment: @Simon The two solder pads ringed in red on the lower left hand side of your photograph are the mains input, before it gets to the transformers. If there is no mains here then the line cord or fuse in the plug are faulty. There is a mains voltage selector on the left as well, but this may not be fitted to the UK version. If there is any mains selection, check that the switches are in the right places. Unplug it first!

Comment: The way the built in fuse is drawn (no winding, just a fuse connection between 5 and 6) would allow for someone to add an external one on the outside. The fuse is probably thermal though so it would defeat its purpose.

Comment: @Simon  In your photograph pin 6 is marked at the top . The neutral side of the mains should appear on pin 5 which is connected via the aforementioned non-replaceable fuse to pin 6 which is one end of half the primary winding. The other end of this winding is pin 4 which is taken off through the voltage selector (if it exists) then the relay and back to pin 2, the second half of the primary, finally it emerges on pin 1, back to the relay and then to the line side of the mains. Test for mains between pins 1 and 6 to start with. When **unplugged** test for fuse continuity between 5 and 6.

Comment: @PeterJennings Voltage Selector is set to 230V-240V.


 When connected to main wall socket, multimeter shows around 240V AC voltage between L and N (in my photoraph) or between pin 1 and 3 (as per page 61 diagram in service manual).


  Multimeter beeps in continuity mode when probes between 5 and 6 (top right in my photograph) or bottom left (as per page 61 diagram in service manual).


  Between 1 and 6 (top right in my photograph) or bottom left (as per page 61 diagram in service manual) there is no voltage when connected to wall socket.

Comment: @Simon So far so good. Power is getting to the board. The fuse appears to be intact. But no mains across 1 and 6 when plugged in and mains switch operated (?). No sound of relay either. So quite possibly the problem lies elsewhere. Unfortunately I think this is about as far as we can take it here. Long distance fault finding on equipment about which I know next to nothing isn't going to work. I fear you need to take it to a dealer for repair.

Comment: @PeterJennings sure . Thank you for the help so far.